# Check if root element exists

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

The program reads the values of the "File" elements of each XML File and do something about it. I need an if statement that checks first if the root element is "CONFIGURATION" (this is the way of checking whether it's the right XML the program is reading). My problem is you cannot add .Any() to .Element, only to .Elements. And my if statement below doesn't work, i need to change it.

Please see the comment before the if statement.

My code:

```
    static void queryData(string xmlFile)
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
        var configuration = xdoc.Element("CONFIGURATION");

        //The code works except for the if statement that I added.
        //The debug shows that configuration is null if no "CONFIGURATION" element is found,
        //therefore it prompts a "NullReferenceException" error.
        if (configuration == xdoc.Element("CONFIGURATION"))
        {
            string sizeMB = configuration.Element("SizeMB").Value;
            string backupLocation = configuration.Element("BackupLocation").Value;
            string[] files = null;

            Console.WriteLine("XML: " + xmlFile);

            if (configuration.Elements("Files").Any())
            {
                files = configuration.Element("Files").Elements("File").Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
            }
            else if (configuration.Elements("Folder").Any())
            {
                files = configuration.Elements("Folder").Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
            }
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(serviceStat, true);
            sw.WriteLine("Working! XML File: " + xmlFile);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(file);
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
        else 
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(serviceStat, true);
            sw.WriteLine("XML Configuration invalid: " + xmlFile);
            sw.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What!? Did I do something wrong to get down votes?

Comment: I agree, why this question has been downvoted ?, apart from that @Blackator, if you want to make sure that you are using the right XML then XML Schema is probably a much better choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't a simple null check work here?

```
    var configuration = xdoc.Element("CONFIGURATION");

    if (configuration != null)
    {
            // code...
    }
```

Comment: The null worked! Thanks! I really look stupid right now.. :) Just asking, is there any other more straightforward way like .Any() in the .Elements()?

Comment: No, a null check is the best way when you are simply checking if an element exists.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do something like this:)

```
if (xdoc.Elements("CONFIGURATION").Any())
{
}
```